# BASH - Stop execution of sourced scripts

Tags: bash

I have a script that runs other scripts with source. What i want to do is to find those scripts being run, and if any of them is running, then stop executing it.
Something like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 source /path/script1.sh
 source /path/sript2.sh
 source /path/sript3.sh

 if [ a_script_is_running ]
 then
      stop_execution scriptn.sh
 fi
```

If one of those scripts was running an infinite loop, is there a way to stop this loop and to continue with the execution of the main script?

Comment: `source` doesn't run in the background.

Comment: You should look up what `source` does. What you want is not possible.

Comment: if one of those scripts was running an infinite loop, is there a way to stop this loop and to continue with the execution of the main script?

Comment: No, because the source'd file *is* part of the main script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is background shells and how to kill them.

The first step is to fork those scripts into the background instead of sourcing them.  Sourcing them just inserts their code into your current script.

So you could do something like:

```
# '&' forks a script into the background
/path/script1.sh &
/path/script2.sh &
/path/script3.sh &
...
# now when you need to make sure that they are all killed
kill $(jobs -p)
```

Explanation of `source`

If I have 3 scripts:

script.1.sh:

```
echo "hello world"
```

script.2.sh:

```
source script.1.sh
source script.1.sh
```

script.3.sh:

```
echo "hello world"
echo "hello world"
```

There is no functional difference between script.3.sh and script.2.sh.  None.  They both will use one shell process (echo is builtin) and will call echo "hello world" twice one after the other.

script4.sh:

```
script.1.sh &
script.1.sh &
```

This one is different.  It forks two background scripts (both called script.1.sh although they will have different process IDs), each of those background processes will echo "hello world" and then exit.  It will look the same, but in this case you could actually kill one of them since they are executing asynchronously from your main script.

Comment: The problem is that I want to source it because I need to share variables between the sourced script and the original

Comment: Using source just includes the script as part of the current script in the same process.  It makes no sense to kill a sourced script, since that is the same script that is already running.  Imaging source just being the same as copy and pasting the other script into your script and you will understand what it does.

Comment: I updated my comment again to try to make things more clear.  If it still doesn't make sense then you will need to study processes and what "source" does.  Try looking at the bash man page (man bash).

Answer (score 0):

A script is not a process, it's only interpreted by the shell (it might spawn other process though). Since it's not a process, it doesn't get assigned a `pid`, which means you couldn't kill it. What you can kill is process started by those other scripts. For example, if `script1.sh` starts a `wget` download, you could then kill that `wget` process ( you'd need its pid in any case, to make sure that's the one you need to kill)

Comment: And how can you know that script1.sh is running wget? I would like to know all the process being run by script1.sh so i can kill them

Comment: It was just an example, you should read `script1.sh` and see what it does and which processes it spawns.

Comment: Generally a script will have a shell process associated with it.  In the case of sourced scripts, there is only the shell process of the first script which sourced it.  The key thing to remember is that sourcing a script just inserts its contents into the current script, it doesn't fork a new process.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic premise is the problem:

```
source /path/script1.sh 
source /path/sript2.sh 
source /path/sript3.sh 

                       <- At this point, all those scripts have run to completion

if [ a_script_is_running ]       <- It won't be!
then 
     stop_execution scriptn.sh   <- Too late!  
fi
```

Test your source'ed files as modular units before using them.
Don't, ever, `source` a file you are not 100% confident in.

You say that you don't run them in background because you need to share the variables: take a look at your design again.

If you need to pass data then consider using a named pipe (a.k.a. a fifo, see `man mkfifo`) or some other form of interprocess communication.